# How can I remove a JPanel from a JFrame?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, multithreading

Recently I asked here [how to add a new JPanel to JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492513/why-i-cannot-add-a-jpanel-to-jframe). The answer helped me to get a working code. But not I have a related question: "How can I remove an old JPanel". I need that because of the following problem.

A new JPanel appears appears when I want (either time limit is exceeded or user press the "Submit" button). But in several seconds some element of the old JPanel appears together with the component of the new JPanel. I do not understand why it happens.

I thought that it is because I have to other threads which update the window. But the first thread just add the old panel once (so, it should be finished). And in the second thread I have a loop which is broken (so, it also should be finished).

Here is my code:

```
private Thread controller = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        // First we set the initial pane (for the selection of partner).
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                frame.getContentPane().add(generatePartnerSelectionPanel());
                frame.invalidate();
                frame.validate();
            }
        });
        // Update the pane for the selection of the parnter.
        for (int i=40; i>0; i=i-1) {
            final int sec = i;
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    timeLeftLabel.setText(sec + " seconds left.");
                }
            });
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) { }

            if (partnerSubmitted) {
                break;
            }
        }
        // For the given user the selection phase is finished (either the time is over or form was submitted).
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                frame.getContentPane().add(generateWaitForGamePanel());
                frame.invalidate();
                frame.validate();
            }
        });

    }
};
```

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of your own question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487658/how-do-i-remove-an-old-jpanel-and-add-a-new-one/2487771#2487771

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the easiest way to remove a component (panel) from a container (frame) is to keep a reference to it, and then call `Container.remove(Component)` ie:

```
private Thread controller = new Thread() {
public void run() {

        final Component panel1 = generatePartnerSelectionPanel();

        // First we set the initial pane (for the selection of partner).
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                frame.getContentPane().add(panel1);
                frame.invalidate();
                frame.validate();
        }
        });
        // Update the pane for the selection of the parnter.
        for (int i=40; i>0; i=i-1) {
            final int sec = i;
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    timeLeftLabel.setText(sec + " seconds left.");
                }
            });
            try {Thread.sleep(1000);} catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            if (partnerSubmitted) {break;}
        }
        // For the given user the selection phase is finished (either the time is over or form was submitted).
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                frame.getContentPane().remove(panel1);
                frame.getContentPane().add(generateWaitForGamePanel());
                frame.invalidate();
                frame.validate();
        }
        });

}
};
```

i haven't tested this code but it should work.

Comment: Thanks! I tested it and it works! It seems to be better than mine solution. It is better to remove it rather than to hide.

Comment: There is also `removeAll()` method if you haven't saved the link to the component(s).

Comment: glad to help Roman. you can click the tick next to the answer if it solves your problem. and yes, removeAll will work fine, provided you don't have any other components in the container.

Comment: Thanks man that answer made my day! 
btw you can also use `this.revalidate();` instead of `frame.invalidate(); frame.validate();`

Answer (score 10):

Its the same whether you do add or remove a component on a visible GUI:

```
panel.remove(...);
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

Comment: `revalidate()` was what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had problems with `requestFocusInWindow` on `TextField` too. The trick is to not construct the components in the `JPanel` constructor. But, make a build method and execute following code after it has been added to the frame.

This worked for me:

```
frame.getContentPane().removeAll(); //or .remove(previousPanel);
frame.getContentPane().add(newPanel);
panel.buildPanel(); // panel needs a builder method
frame.revalidate(); // in- and validate in one !! 
frame.pack(); //
```

if you want to resize, you need `preferredSize();` on panel or use `repaint()` if you don't need to resize frame.

Answer (score 0):

Roman, the problem can be solved like that:

1. Do this in the beginning of your `run` method:

`final JPanel partnerSelectionPanel = generatePartnerSelectionPanel();`

2. Then do this

`frame.getContentPane().add(partnerSelectionPanel);`

3. Before you add the new panel do this:

`partnerSelectionPanel.setVisible(false);`

It works. I do not know if it is a safe and/or elegant solution but it works.

Comment: I think using setVisible is a better solution then adding and removing the panel.