# Remove Jframe panels

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, frame

```
JFrame frame1 = new JFrame("frame");
frame1.setVisible(true);
frame1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
JPanel Panel1 = new JPanel();
JPanel Panel2 = new JPanel();
frame1.add(Panel1,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
frame1.add(Panel2,BorderLayout.North);
```

How do i do something like this that if something happens the frame is blank

```
if(SOMETHINGHAPPENS)
   {
     //remove all panels from frame 1 so i have a blank frame 
    //now i want to add some new panels
   }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501861/how-can-i-remove-a-jpanel-from-a-jframe may help. In other words, use `frame1.remove()`.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks. Java 7, it does: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#remove(java.awt.Component) I am not sure about previous versions though.

Comment: @NicolásCarlo Yeah, it's `removeAll` that does freakish stuff

Comment: To remove all panels, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347076/how-to-remove-all-components-from-a-jframe-in-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple answer, don't.

Instead, use a [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) on the `JFrame`

This will allow you to setup a series of "views" which you can switch between as needed

Comment: trying to look into cardlayouts will mark as right answer if it all worksout thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @MadProgrammer can u please assist me with how to implement cards into this i followed a online tutorial doesn't seem to function tho

Comment: @lilz4life [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17477891/how-do-i-use-cardlayout-for-my-java-program-for-login-and-menu-items/17479575#17479575)

Comment: @MadProgrammer in this example they use card layouts to navigate within single panels although my frame displays multiple panels

for exmaple at the moment i have 2 panels then when something happens i want to display multiple other panels do

Comment: @lilz4life And?  Make a view, which contains multiple panels.  This will act as a single view from the perspective of the `CardLayout`, but will display multiple different components.  The concept of what you were originally trying to do hasn't changed, the method by which you achieve it has...

Comment: OOOO i think im on the right track instead of adding them to a view i added all the others to a single panel is that okay? or should i look into views

Comment: Add as much or as little as you need.  A individual "card" or "view" is just a container, which you can switch to as you need...

Comment: WOHOOOO WORKED <3 THANKS MAN appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#remove%28java.awt.Component%29). `Jframe.remove(JPanel)`. Then call `JFrame.pack()`
, and possibly `JFrame.repaint()` in order to refresh the graphics if necessary.

JPanel extends JComponent, so it should work just fine. Remember to substitute JFrame and JPanel in the code above with the names of the frames/panels you are using the methods on.

Comment: any way to remove all panels instead of individually doing it

Comment: @lilz4life Try http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#removeAll()